# margins in between pagination links

Tags: pagination

Any ideas how I could increase the spaces between the pagination links on my site?

http://guvno.com/

I'm guessing adding some padding code to the custom.css maybe?

I'm a beginner.

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, try this in the custom.css file:
`.wp-pagenavi a { margin-right: 5px; }`